# How to change ssl certyficate JBoss AS 6.1.0.Final

Tags: security, ssl, jboss, ssl-certificate

I'm using `JBoss AS 6.1.0.Final` and in the `standalone/conf/` directory, I have my `cert.pfx` file.

I suppose that this is the ssl certificate file.  So now if I want to change the ssl certificate to new `.pfx` file all i have to do is replace old file with new one? Does jboss need to be stopped before it or it needs to be rebooted after ?

Generally is that proper way of change ssl certificate on `JBoss AS 6.1.0.Final` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If ssl certificate doesn't have password replacing it should just work.

If ssl certificate does have a password, it will need to be changed in deploy/jbossweb.sar/serwer.xml.

And of course restart the server updating the certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just replace the old certificate with the new certificate and restart the server.  Life should be good.